# Why compiler cannot infer generic types of the inner class in Java?

Tags: java, generics, language-lawyer, type-inference, inner-classes

```java
class A<T>
{
    class InnerA<U>
    {}
}

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        A<Integer>.InnerA<String> var = new A<>().new InnerA<>();
    }
}
```

When the above code snippet is compiled, it leads to Compile-Time error saying "incompatible types: cannot infer type arguments for `A.InnerA<>`. It seems to me that the Compiler should be able to infer the types to be `InnerA<String>`.

Why is it not able to do so? It would be helpful if someone could explain how it works behind the scene.

Comment: Thats a limitation of JAVA / JVM AFAIR: Unable to interfere two generic types in a row.
You need to excplicit set the Types on the right side

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler error message is misleading.

The compiler can only infer the type of an expression from the left hand side of an assignment, if the expression is the one whose result is actually assigned. In your example, `new A<>()` is not assigned, but just used for a qualified instantiation of the inner class¹. Since there is no assignment context for `new A<>()`, the compiler infers `new A<Object>()`.

For the `.new InnerA<>()`, there is an assignment context and the compiler tries to infer the result type using the left hand side of the assignment but fails because `A`’s type is already incompatible. In the shortened compiler message, the failure to infer a type for `InnerA` is visible but not the reason of the mismatching type argument for `A`.

The long error message looks like

```
Main.java:11: error: incompatible types: cannot infer type arguments for A.InnerA<>
        A<Integer>.InnerA<String> var = new A<>().new InnerA<>();
                                                            ^
  reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) U exist
          so that A<Object>.InnerA<U> conforms to A<Integer>.InnerA<String>

  where U is a type-variable:
    U extends Object declared in class A.InnerA
```

So the issue still is reported as “*can’t find a type for `U`*” but we can also see that the deeper reason is that no `U` can ever solve the problem of having mismatching types for `A<T>`.

We can also demonstrate the actual cause by changing the line to

```java
A<Integer>.InnerA<String> var = new A<>().new InnerA<String>();
```

providing the right type for `InnerA` and now getting

```
incompatible types:
    A<Object>.InnerA<String> cannot be converted to A<Integer>.InnerA<String>
```

or changing the line to

```java
A<Integer>.InnerA<String> var = new A<Integer>().new InnerA<>();
```

which will solve the problem, as now `A` has the right type and the type for `InnerA` can be inferred from the left hand side.

---

¹ the same issue arises if you have `genericMethod1().method2()`

Comment: I could understand most part but *Since there is no assignment context for `new A<>()`, the compiler infers `new A<Object>()`*. Why does it not happen in the case of `A<Integer> var = new A<>();`?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash because then, you have an assignment context. As hinted in the footnote, the issue always arises when you have a chain like `Type var = expr1 [.expr2] [.expr3] .lastExpression;`. The left hand side `Type` will only be used for inference of `lastExpression`. So for all preceding expressions, only their standalone type will be used. Which means inferring `Object` when the type parameter has no other constraints. When there is no chain on the right hand side, type inference will always work for the entire expression.